# For an element, Prove there exist finitely many polynomials in a set Y such that u is a 0 of them iff u is a 0 of all polynomials in Y

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let F be a field and let Y be a set of polynomials in k variables over F.
Prove that there exist finitely many polynomials f_{1}, . . . , f_{m} ∈ Y such that for
u_{1}, . . . , u_{k} ∈ F^k
,
f( u_{1} , . . . , u_{k}) = 0 ∀f ∈ Y ⇐⇒ f_{j} (u_{1}, . . . , u_{k}) = 0 for j = 1, . . .m.

Is the finite set of polynomials meant to be some type of basis for all the polynomials in Y? Help knowing how to approach the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are using something similar to TeX syntax, but not quite.. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

The set of polynomials $f$ such that $ f( u_{1} , . . . , u_{k}) = 0 $ is an ideal $I$ of the ring $F[X_1,\ldots,X_k]$ which is a noetherian ring as $F$ is a noetherian ring (it is a field !) This ideal is therefore generated by finitely many polynomials $ f_{1}, . . . , f_{m} \in I$.